# Trying to get subcategory of current category

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I am trying to get subcategory of current category using `wp_dropdown_categories` .

onclick of category, i want to get subcategory. I did try using `get_categories` function with arguments but it's not giving me subcategories. While using `has_children` is giving me blank array.

This is my code:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_wp_get_subcategory', 'wp_get_subcategory' );

function wp_get_subcategory() {
    $parent_cat_ID = $_POST['selected_category'];

    $args = array(
     'child_of' => $parent_cat_ID,
     'taxonomy' => 'download_category',
     'hide_empty' => 0,
     'hierarchical' => false,
     'depth'  => 1,
     'parent' => $parent_cat_ID
    );

    if ( isset($parent_cat_ID) ) {
        $has_children = get_categories($args);

        if ( $has_children ) {

            //wp_dropdown_categories($args);
            foreach ($has_children as $category) {

                $option = '<option value="'.$category->cat_ID.'">';
                $option .= $category->cat_name;
                echo $option .= '</option>';

            }
        } else {
            ?><select name="sub_cat_disabled" id="sub_cat_disabled" disabled="disabled"><option>No child categories!</option></select><?php
        }
        die();    
    }
}
```

Comment: now i am getting subcategories thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this two example i have take this from some reference website. I hope this  may useful to you

1. List subcategories if viewing a Category, and brothers / sibling
   categories if in subcategory.

   ```
   <?php

    if (is_category()) {
    $this_category = get_category($cat);
   }
   ?>

   <?php
    if($this_category->category_parent)
     $this_category = wp_list_categories('orderby=id&show_count=0
     &title_li=&use_desc_for_title=1&child_of='.$this_category->category_parent."&echo=0"); 
     else $this_category = wp_list_categories('orderby=id&depth=1&show_count=0
     &title_li=&use_desc_for_title=1&child_of='.$this_category->cat_ID.     "&echo=0");
     if ($this_category) { ?> 

     <ul>
     <?php echo $this_category; ?>
      </ul>
       <?php } ?>
   ```
2. Suppose the category whose subcategories you want to show is category 10, and that its category “nicename” is “archives”.

   ```
   <select name="event-dropdown"> 
   <option value=""><?php echo esc_attr_e( 'Select Event', 'textdomain' ); ?></option> 
    <?php 
    $categories = get_categories( array( 'child_of' => 10 ); 
    foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
    printf( '<option value="%1$s">%2$s (%3$s)</option>',
       esc_attr( '/category/archives/' . $category->category_nicename ),
       esc_html( $category->cat_name ),
       esc_html( $category->category_count )
      );
    }
   ?>
   </select>
   ```

For Reference: [click me](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_categories/)

Answer (score 1):

That's best if you are getting categories now, as far as your older code looks there is one minor mistake that's why your categories are not showing properly. Just change your

```
'hierarchical' => false,
```

to

```
'hierarchical' => true,
```

and so, your categories will be showing up nicely.